# Defining/algorithm, python

Tags: python

Recently I started to learn python.
There was a need for the program.
Please point the track :
The program takes two values from a file: the enterprise and the number of people in them.
Next i need to make the following calculating : finding company with the fewest people - > define it as one part of all - > count ratio is less than all other companies - > count of the number of rations for some time, uniformly.
First, I don't know, what i need to do first. Should i define all data like this "Company = numbers", or do a dict? 
I don't ask to solve the problem - I ask to teach. 
B.R.

Comment: it is not place to teach.

Comment: Please try to make your questions more clear and structured. Also StackOverflow is meant to questions direct to the point. 
I recommend you to read the following posts: 

[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

for your example if you want to keep it as easy as possible put all your data in dicts you don't need to create database or file to store the data, for each entity you have to create its variable as dict and make the relationship between them with id like this : we assume that we have client and orders entities:

```
client = {
1:{"name":"name_1","email":"name_1@gmail.com"},
2:{"name":"name_2","email":"name_2@gmail.com"}
}
orders={1:{"date":"2016-02-01","client_id":1}...}
```

and so on.